# Naming convention for the response model of an API

Tags: json, rest, naming-conventions

There is a REST API for which I have to describe to response model. It is a simple Get API, fetching different data from underlying systems. I am using camelCase
There are a lot of self explanatory data like usual lastName, firstName, etc...
I am using explicit endings to define the data retrieved like wordWordDate and wordWordAmount.
If it is retrieving a value that needs to be interpreted, I wonder if I shold use a specific ending as well, meaning the value is a code, which has a specific meaning.

Now part of the response are lists and some are just fixed attributes. I wonder if it makes sense to give an indication if that is a list or not.

For codes I used wordWordCode
For lists I used wordWordInfos
For attributes I used wordWordDetails
a typical response for a house would be:

```
{
 {"body":
   {"roomInfos":
    [{"identifier": "01", "name": "garage", "hasWindow": true, "squareMeter": 20},
     {"identifier": "02", "name": "kitchen", "hasWindow": true, "squareMeter": 15}
    ]
   }
   {"featureDetails": 
    {"squareMeter": 100, "faceCount": 3, "hasYard": true}
   }
 }
}
```

I have doubt if this naming convention is appropriate. I would like it to be unambiguous and clear. Yet, in this example, I would replace roomInfos to rooms, plural to make it has a list.
However, the features of the house are also more than 1 there are the surface, the number of face and the yard boolean. So I would tend to also replace featureDetails by features, plural.
Doing so will make it hard to if that is a list or not. Maybe I am overthinking this and solved auto-magically by the data type but I would like also to make it clear in the documentation.

Any help or external reference to best practice would help much.